# [Create3] /battery_state topic time stamp and data repeated 17 times?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Create3 publishes a /battery_state topic roughly every 10 seconds, but the header time stamp and data changes every 169 seconds.

**Is this a defect, and if so where do I file the issue?**

```
---
header:
  stamp:
    sec: 1668885286
    nanosec: 307109232
  frame_id: ''
voltage: 14.880000114440918
temperature: 42.45000076293945
current: 0.42100000381469727
charge: 0.9739999771118164
capacity: 2.049999952316284
design_capacity: 2.049999952316284
percentage: 0.47999998927116394

---
header:
  stamp:
    sec: 1668885463              <<--- TimeStamp and Data Changed
    nanosec: 885139612
  frame_id: ''
voltage: 14.902000427246094
temperature: 42.54999923706055
current: 0.4269999861717224
charge: 0.9950000047683716
capacity: 2.049999952316284
design_capacity: 2.049999952316284
percentage: 0.49000000953674316


---
header:
  stamp:
    sec: 1668885463
    nanosec: 885139612
  frame_id: ''
voltage: 14.902000427246094
temperature: 42.54999923706055
current: 0.4269999861717224
charge: 0.9950000047683716
capacity: 2.049999952316284
design_capacity: 2.049999952316284
percentage: 0.49000000953674316


---
header:
  stamp:
    sec: 1668885463
    nanosec: 885139612
  frame_id: ''
voltage: 14.902000427246094
temperature: 42.54999923706055
current: 0.4269999861717224
charge: 0.9950000047683716
capacity: 2.049999952316284
design_capacity: 2.049999952316284
percentage: 0.49000000953674316


---
header:
  stamp:
    sec: 1668885463
    nanosec: 885139612
  frame_id: ''
voltage: 14.902000427246094
temperature: 42.54999923706055
current: 0.4269999861717224
charge: 0.9950000047683716
capacity: 2.049999952316284
design_capacity: 2.049999952316284
percentage: 0.49000000953674316


---
header:
  stamp:
    sec: 1668885463
    nanosec: 885139612
  frame_id: ''
voltage: 14.902000427246094
temperature: 42.54999923706055
current: 0.4269999861717224
charge: 0.9950000047683716
capacity: 2.049999952316284
design_capacity: 2.049999952316284
percentage: 0.49000000953674316


---
header:
  stamp:
    sec: 1668885463
    nanosec: 885139612
  frame_id: ''
voltage: 14.902000427246094
temperature: 42.54999923706055
current: 0.4269999861717224
charge: 0.9950000047683716
capacity: 2.049999952316284
design_capacity: 2.049999952316284
percentage: 0.49000000953674316


---
header:
  stamp:
    sec: 1668885463
    nanosec: 885139612
  frame_id: ''
voltage: 14.902000427246094
temperature: 42.54999923706055
current: 0.4269999861717224
charge: 0.9950000047683716
capacity: 2.049999952316284
design_capacity: 2.049999952316284
percentage: 0.49000000953674316


---
header:
  stamp:
    sec: 1668885463
    nanosec: 885139612
  frame_id: ''
voltage: 14.902000427246094
temperature: 42.54999923706055
current: 0.4269999861717224
charge: 0.9950000047683716
capacity: 2.049999952316284
design_capacity: 2.049999952316284
percentage: 0.49000000953674316


---
header:
  stamp:
    sec: 1668885463
    nanosec: 885139612
  frame_id: ''
voltage: 14.902000427246094
temperature: 42.54999923706055
current: 0.4269999861717224
charge: 0.9950000047683716
capacity: 2.049999952316284
design_capacity: 2.049999952316284
percentage: 0.49000000953674316


---
header:
  stamp:
    sec: 1668885463
    nanosec: 885139612
  frame_id: ''
voltage: 14.902000427246094
temperature: 42.54999923706055
current: 0.4269999861717224
charge: 0.9950000047683716
capacity: 2.049999952316284
design_capacity: 2.049999952316284
percentage: 0.49000000953674316


---
header:
  stamp:
    sec: 1668885463
    nanosec: 885139612
  frame_id: ''
voltage: 14.902000427246094
temperature: 42.54999923706055
current: 0.4269999861717224
charge: 0.9950000047683716
capacity: 2.049999952316284
design_capacity: 2.049999952316284
percentage: 0.49000000953674316


---
header:
  stamp:
    sec: 1668885463
    nanosec: 885139612
  frame_id: ''
voltage: 14.902000427246094
temperature: 42.54999923706055
current: 0.4269999861717224
charge: 0.9950000047683716
capacity: 2.049999952316284
design_capacity: 2.049999952316284
percentage: 0.49000000953674316


---
header:
  stamp:
    sec: 1668885463
    nanosec: 885139612
  frame_id: ''
voltage: 14.902000427246094
temperature: 42.54999923706055
current: 0.4269999861717224
charge: 0.9950000047683716
capacity: 2.049999952316284
design_capacity: 2.049999952316284
percentage: 0.49000000953674316


---
header:
  stamp:
    sec: 1668885463
    nanosec: 885139612
  frame_id: ''
voltage: 14.902000427246094
temperature: 42.54999923706055
current: 0.4269999861717224
charge: 0.9950000047683716
capacity: 2.049999952316284
design_capacity: 2.049999952316284
percentage: 0.49000000953674316


---
header:
  stamp:
    sec: 1668885463
    nanosec: 885139612
  frame_id: ''
voltage: 14.902000427246094
temperature: 42.54999923706055
current: 0.4269999861717224
charge: 0.9950000047683716
capacity: 2.049999952316284
design_capacity: 2.049999952316284
percentage: 0.49000000953674316

---
header:
  stamp:
    sec: 1668885463
    nanosec: 885139612
  frame_id: ''
voltage: 14.902000427246094
temperature: 42.54999923706055
current: 0.4269999861717224
charge: 0.9950000047683716
capacity: 2.049999952316284
design_capacity: 2.049999952316284
percentage: 0.49000000953674316

---
header:
  stamp:
    sec: 1668885463
    nanosec: 885139612
  frame_id: ''
voltage: 14.902000427246094
temperature: 42.54999923706055
current: 0.4269999861717224
charge: 0.9950000047683716
capacity: 2.049999952316284
design_capacity: 2.049999952316284
percentage: 0.49000000953674316

---
header:
  stamp:
    sec: 1668885632            <<-- TimeStamp and Data Changed
    nanosec: 998287917
  frame_id: ''
voltage: 14.92300033569336
temperature: 42.54999923706055
current: 0.4230000078678131
charge: 1.0149999856948853
capacity: 2.049999952316284
design_capacity: 2.049999952316284
percentage: 0.5
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/409609/%5Bcreate3%5D-/battery_state-topic-time-stamp-and-data-repeated-17-times?/) by [RobotDreams](https://answers.ros.org/users/40559/robotdreams/) on ROS Answers with karma: 327 on 2022-11-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Found answer to both questions:

2. Questions and Issues about the Create3: https://github.com/iRobotEducation/create3_docs/discussions

[image: image description]

1. It is by design:

https://github.com/iRobotEducation/create3_docs/discussions/243#discussioncomment-4187712

---

Originally posted by [RobotDreams](https://answers.ros.org/users/40559/robotdreams/) with karma: 327 on 2022-11-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0